# List not passing between methods inside a class definition

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to create a simple class that inputs a list then appends to the list with a function called "add" which is also defined in the same class.

I keep getting this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'a'

```
class try1:
    def __init__(self, a=[]):
        self.a = a
        print(a)
        return

    def add(self, b=None):
        self.a.append(b)
        print(a)
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c=try1(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    d = ['d', 'e', 'f']
    try1.add(d)
```

Comment: What, **exactly** is your indentation? I suspect your `add` definition is outside the `class` block.

Comment: Whatever other problems you may have, please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple different things going on here which cause this weird-looking error.

The core problem is that you're trying to call `add` on the **class** `try1`, not the **instance** you just created, in the variable `c`. Changing `try1.add(d)` to `c.add(d)` produces the expected result (if you also remove the `print(a)` or change it to `print(self.a)`, since `a` doesn't exist in that scope).

The unrelated-looking error is because you made `b` a keyword argument. When you try to call `try1.add`, the first argument becomes `self` inside the method. Then you get an `AttributeError` because `self` is a list, which obviously doesn't have an attribute named `a`.

Also, you [shouldn't use a mutable as a default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). Additionally, you don't need empty `return` statements: any function without a `return` statement implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Thank you!! 
I appreciate the added clarifying info as well! I'm a very green coder so everything is a bit overwhelming rn.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. First of all, fix that indentation. Python is really specific about whitespace. Assuming you fix the indentation, you'll come into a couple of other issues. In your `main` method, you want to be calling `c.add(d)` (I think).

You're probably running into an error on line 9, which is the error I think you're talking about. In the scope of your method, the variable `a` doesn't exist yet. `self.a` does, though. You probably mean to print `self.a`.

As a side note, class names in Python should start with an uppercase letter. Numbers are allowed, but I'd really try and avoid them.